# Client side validation return "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'presence' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation

I have on one page 2 forms for the model `User` - and this is the problem, why I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'presence' of undefined`. When I remove one **form_for @user**, so the **Client Side Validations** works well. But not if on one page are two models and two forms **@user**.

But the problem is, that I need to have on one page this model and form twice. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the second error you describe in the comments, i.e. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_user[name]' of undefined` was apparently caused by a transposed form ID.

There is an issue on ClientSideValidation about it here:

https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/325

Adding `html => { id: 'user_new' }` to the `form_for` call solved the issue. I now call the method like this (modified from Devise's original template):

```
<%= form_for(resource,
  :as => resource_name,
  :validate => true,
  :html => { id: 'user_new' },
  :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use different param identifiers for both users:

```
<!-- First form for user -->
<%= form_for(@user, :as => :first_user) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<!-- Second form for user on the same page -->
<%= form_for(@user, :as => :second_user) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to use identifiers, but when I did it, I got the error message (JS error) `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_user[name]' of undefined`